# Ruby API response as lower camel case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers, camelcasing

I'm trying to return the API response as lowerCamelCase but it is not working, I need to do this for all my Controllers/fields so I need a solution for entire project.

I've tried a lot of stuff, including this (http://brentvatne.ca/automatic-casing-activemodel-serializer/) who tells me to configure Activemodel to lower_camel as following

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.key_format = :lower_camel
```

But that is not working, it is returning the following json

```
{
    "users": [{
        "id": "56b110089c28691b84a3bd73",
        "first_name": "Lucas"
    }]
}
```

I need to transform the first_name into firstName.

Versions:

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.5

ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [i386-mingw32]
```

And the gems

```
active_model_serializers (0.10.0.rc4)
rails-api (0.4.0)
```

My ember App recognize the JSON but I don't want to use snake case variables on JS

Comment: Are you sure that's the right json? It's got an open square bracket but no close square bracket.

Comment: It'd be better to put active model serializer tag to your question, since this question is specific to that gem. Also, make sure that you've restarted your rails server... it's embarrassing to admit but I've made that mistake before.

Comment: @Harfangk I've tried that many times, it actually hit a breakpoint on that line but does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on the version of Active Model Serializer (0.10.0rc2).

On the last stable version ([0.9](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable)) there was an [issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/748) that has been merged to fix the camelCase but this same PR is not present on the 0.10 RC versions.

So after I have downgraded the gem it worked :)

Answer (score 14):

Boom! I found it! I had to dig through the AMS repo (and eventually stumbled upon a helpful readme) but here it is for v0.10:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :camel_lower
```

Put that in an initializer.

There are also other options: `:dash`, `:camel`, `:underscore`, and `:unaltered`, and `nil`

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/a032201a91cbca407211bca0392ba881eef1f7ba/docs/general/configuration_options.md

Answer (score 1):

Search a project for `key_format` in case it's overridden somewhere.

Please try it in the console, try to set `key_format` explicitly to make sure it's possible (ex `MySerializer.new(object, key_format: :lower_camel).as_json`)

If it doesn't help you can put here code example how you are using serializers.

Comment: This is not working in 0.10.0r4. The above code only returns an error asking for missing template.